# Masonry: Can't eliminate vertical gap

Tags: javascript, html, css, browserify, masonry

I am using Masonry in my site. The following is my HTML :

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="A"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="B"></div>
    ....many more photos....
</div>
```

The following is the CSS (SASS) :

```
* {
        @include box-sizing(border-box);
    }
    .grid {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .grid:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        clear: both;
    }
    .grid-sizer {
        width: 30%;
    }
    .grid-item {
        float: left;
        width: 30%;
        img {
            display: block;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

My JavaScript, using Browserify :

```
var Masonry = require('masonry-layout');
var docReady = require('doc-ready');
var imagesLoaded = require('imagesloaded');

docReady( function() {
   var grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
   var msnry = new Masonry( grid, {
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
      percentPosition: true
   });
   imagesLoaded( grid, function() {
      msnry.layout();
  });

 });
```

There are many large vertical gaps in the resulting images. I think I have already copied and pasted the code in the example shown in Masonry.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: a **[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/?html,output)** or a **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)** will give you much better chances of a good and fast answer!

Comment: Incidentally, Masonry doesn't claim to be able to eliminate gaps in all directions. Unless your items are all the correct size and order, there most likely will be some present. http://packery.metafizzy.co/ might be a better alternative for you.

Comment: very sorry that i can't get a fiddle for this. the vertical gap is not small, as large as the height of the image. So there must be something wrong with the image size.

Comment: @J4G Thanks for the answer. So how should I prepare the images to make the best use of Masonry?

Comment: Equal widths or heights for all of the images is really the only way to guarantee no unnecessary gaps.